# Count entries that have different values in other column

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by, having

Here is an (simplified) example of DB I have (sorry for the ulgy format, I don't know how to write tables):

```
Name | Num  
John | 1  
John | 3  
John | 4  
Dany | 2  
Andy | 5  
Andy | 5
```

I want to count how many people have more at least two different Numbers.

For instance, here, only john, because he has `1`, `3` and `4`.
Not Andy because he has twice 2 and no other one.
And obviously not Dany because he has only one entry.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Does that matter? Standard ANSI/ISO SQL should do fine in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
select count(name) from table group by name having count(distinct num)>1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and to everyone else too !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT A.Num) cnt 
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY A.Name
HAVING cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: ANSI SQL does not allow column aliases in the having clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from (
    select Name from Temp group by Name having count(distinct num) > 1
) as a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name from `table` group by name,num having count(num)>1
```